# Allow selection of a subset of user records within a Flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I am working to build out a small project management type app for our org. We have a "Project__c" object with a "Project_team__c" object which has a child relationship to Project__c.

When a user is added as a project member, and entry is created in the Project_Team object and the Project_Team__c.Member field is set to the new Project Team members UserId. So far adding team members works fine.

We have a separate custom object named "Project_To_Dos__c" which also has a child relationship to Project__c. Within this object the intention is to list high level items which need to be addressed as a part of the project completion, and these individual todays may have tasks, etc. associated with them.

I would like to use a Flow to add Project To Do items to that object, and within that Flow I would like to be able to select a Project Member as the responsible party for a given To Do. However, I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to best approach this as well as whether what I am trying to do is even possible.

I am finding that you cannot pass a record collection to be used a choice set and have seen some other users suggest Apex for this. However, returning the users via Apex if I'm not mistaken would pass that list back as a record collection which I believe leaves me with the same issue unless I am mistaken. Am I over thinking this? Is anyone able to recommend a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is looking for this type of functionality the "Unofficial Lookup Component" found at https://unofficialsf.com/lookup/ worked perfectly to achieve what I need to accomplish here.